# Setting a maximum on a number column based on a column from the same list

Tags: list, column

I have a list with 3 columns. Title, amount and progress.

Amount and progress are both number types. Is it possible for the progress column's maximum value to be the value of the amount column of the same item?

If not, is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the Validation Settings.

Go to List Settings -> Validation Settings and add a formula for this:

```
=progress<amount
```

And add a User Message telling the user that Progress cannot be larger than the Amount or something.

Comment: I don't see the validation settings link in the settings page. Is it possible that it's a permission issue?

Comment: Note that I'm running SharePoint 2007.

Comment: aha, its not available in 2007 i'm afraid :\ Then you need to make something yourself using javascript, or maybe there are some other solutions out there. Haven't worked on 2007 solutions for sometime tbh :)