# Setting Maximum Value in a List Column as a Calculation

Tags: list, column

I have a list in which I would like the maximum possible numerical value for one column to be dependent on the column before it. (Ex: Value in Column b can't be larger than value in Column a)

Is there a way to set the parameters on this column as a calculation instead of a single value?

Comment: with ref to your example, Who will fill the value of column A, and will it be new in every item.

Comment: @Gaurravs The value in column A will be set by anyone entering the data for this line item and may be different each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to list settings
- Open that column B
- In columns validation section just add below formula

If you want to include that maximum value use below formula

```
 = Column A >= Column B
```

If you want to exclude that maximum value use below formula

```
 = Column A > Column B
```

In addition you can add some message to be displayed when user enters Column B value more than column A.

**Note**:

- Considered that both are numeric columns in type, if not formula needs to be modified
- User must enter column A value first, else you will keep on getting error message

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I was able to find the answer to this question here:
[Setting a maximum on a number column based on a column from the same list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68060/setting-a-maximum-on-a-number-column-based-on-a-column-from-the-same-list?rq=1)